# Why is the nucleon axial charge a charge?

Tags: nuclear-physics

Lets take a look at the definition of the nucleon axial charge $g_A$

$\langle p|A^a_\mu|p\rangle = g_A \bar u(p)\gamma_\mu\gamma_5\tau^au(p)$ with the QCD axial current $A^a_\mu=\bar\psi\gamma_\mu\gamma_5\tau^a\psi$.

Synonymous to "nucleon axial charge" the term "(isovector) axial coupling constant" is used.

What is the motivation to call the object in front of the Dirac spinors a "charge"? Does this have to do with Noether's theorem which states that to each continuous symmetry there's a conserved current with an associated conserved charge? If so, what is the conserved symmetry in the case of the baryon axial charge in general, or the nucleon axial charge in particular?

Second part of the question: Is there a Feynman diagram vertex corresponding to the above matrix element $\langle p|A^a_\mu|p\rangle$? Let me elaborate: The matrix element $\langle \pi|\bar q \gamma_\mu q |\pi\rangle$ is the vector current between two pions and describes the coupling of a photon to a pion and can be drawn as three-particle interaction, namely an incoming pion, a photon and an outgoing pion. A further example would be the flavor-changing charged current $W^{-/+}$ which is represented by the "vector minus axial" current $\langle p|\bar\psi_1\gamma_\mu(1+\gamma_5)\psi_2|n\rangle$. Thus, this can be represented as an incoming neutron, a $W$-boson and an outgoing proton. Thus, asked again: Is there a similar representation for the axial vector matrix element?

Comment: Charge is just a generic term. We have the standard *electrical* charge, but also things like *color* charge. I'm not a QFT guy, so take this with a grain of salt. I'd imagine axial charge has to do with the axial current, although its conservation is broken by an anomaly.

Comment: yes, I think it goes along these line. In QED the coupling at a vertex in a Feynman diagram is proportional to $e$, the electric charge. Thus, in analogy to this, the coupling of quarks (in a nucleon) to the axial-vector $A^a_\mu$ is also called a charge. I think that is where it comes from (and not from Noether's currents).